# Is a p-adic number field and a finite algebraic extension of it ultrametric?

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, local-field

An ultrametric space is a special kind of metric space in which the triangle inequality is replaced with $d(x,z)\leq\max\left\{d(x,y),d(y,z)\right\}$.

Is a p-adic number field and a finite algebraic extension of it ultrametric?

This theorem asserts that a p-adic number field and a finite algebraic extension of it are not ultrametric:

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't say "replaced", because it still holds (ultrametric imply triangle).

Comment: This theorem does not say that. What Theorem 4-12 says is that, if the characteristic of a local field is positive, then this field is ultrametric; the case $char(k)=0$ may be archimedean (the cases $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb C$) or ultrametric (the finite extensions of $\Bbb Q_p$).